# .htaccess proxy monorepo apps in Cloudways

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, monorepo, cloudways

I have a monorepo apps in my Cloudways server and I thought I could configure through nginx sites-enabled, but turns out they configure things through .htaccess file.

Apparently I have never touched any .htaccess file before so I'm pretty confused on how to configure it for monorepo.

Current configuration (default from Cloudways)

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost:3000/ [P,L]
```

Nginx proxy sample

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/ubuntu/apps/my-app;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.com sub.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

My plan is to start 2 apps in 2 different ports using pm2 and I will proxy them by server_name like nginx do but I don't know how.